# Hide Loading tile animation overlay bing V8

Tags: bing-maps, bing, bing-api

Is there a way to hide the loading tile animation overlay on Bing V8? Please help.

[image: Loading tile animation overlay]

Answer (score 1):

Set the loadingScreen property of the animated tile layer to a custom overlay that doesn't display anything. Try this:

```
//Define a custom overlay class that inherits from the CustomOverlay class.
MyCustomOverlay.prototype = new Microsoft.Maps.CustomOverlay();

//Define a constructor for the custom overlay class.
function MyCustomOverlay() {
}

MyCustomOverlay.prototype.onAdd = function () {
    //Logic to perform when adding overlay to map.
};

MyCustomOverlay.prototype.onLoad = function () {
    //Logic to perform after overlay has been added to the map.
};

MyCustomOverlay.prototype.onRemove = function () {
    //Logic to perform when overlay has been removed from the map.
};

//Implement the new custom overlay class.
var overlay = new MyCustomOverlay();

var animatedLayer = new Microsoft.Maps.AnimatedTileLayer({ mercator: tileSources, loadingScreen: overlay});
map.layers.insert(animatedLayer);
```